# Getting the sum of numbers from a text file

Tags: java

Text File:

```
2 3
5 5
6 6
3 4
3 4
4 5
5 6
3 3
4 5
```

For school, one part of a program we had to make was to get "The sum of the scores on the hole that is the highest for all the holes played." Basically, the program had to read from the text file above, and had to display which line had the highest sum. For example, line 1 has a sum of 5, line 2 has a sum of 10, etc. The output should be "12", since line 3 has the highest sum.

What I tried to do was to create two variables: `currentSumScore` and `sumScores`. `currentSumScore` was a test, and `sumScores` would contain the highest sum.

```
for (int roundNum = 1; roundNum <= 9; roundNum++)
{               
    player1Score = in.nextInt();
    player2Score = in.nextInt();

    currentSumScore = player1Score + player2Score;
    if (currentSumScore >= player1Score + player2Score)
    {
        sumScores = currentSumScore;
    }

    else
    {
        sumScores = player1Score + player2Score;    
    }
}
```

What I tried doing here was to add the first two numbers of the first line and set that equal to `currentSumScore`. Then, I put in an if-else. If line 2 had a sum that was greater than line 1, ten `sumScores` would replace that. I tried this but it is only returning the sum of the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
currentSumScore = player1Score + player2Score;
    if (currentSumScore >= player1Score + player2Score)
```

You make currentSumScore to be the sum of player1Score + player2Score, so when it checks the if condition, it will always be true. You need to compare the current sum with the greater value found until then.

```
currentSumScore = player1Score + player2Score;
if (currentSumScore >= sumScores )
{
    //Actual sum is greater than previous
    sumScores = currentSumScore;
}

else
{
    //Do nothing, this line is not greater than one found before
    //This else is not needed
}
```

And start with a sumScores of a small value so the first line will always be greater (0, -1...)

Answer (score 0):

`currentSumScore = player1Score + player2Score;
    if (currentSumScore >= player1Score + player2Score)`

You are setting currentSumScore = player1Score + player2Score

Then you are saying if it is > OR = to. It is always going to be equal to hence the line before it.

Start with `currentSumScore = 0` before reading any of the scores and then check to see if player1Score + player2Score is >, not >=.

Answer (score 0):

You must check against the last value you saved in

> sumScores

```
if (currentSumScore > sumScores) {
     sumScores = currentSumScore;
}
```

And no need to else part. Give this a try, it should work.